# install4j - build only installer and not data files

Tags: install4j

Is there any way to build only the installer without having to repackage the external/downloadable data files at build time?

Say for example I modified just a script in the installer and not the structure or the contents of the files and I'd like to use the previously generated data files but have a new installer.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a planned feature for a future version, as of 5.1.8 this is not possible.